# Can I use JavaScript to set inline style for an element as I am rendering it in the HTML? I would like to define positioning based on a previous div

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML as follows:

```
<html>

    <body>
        <div>
            things
        </div>

        <div style='top: [same top as last div - could be anywhere]px; position: absolute;'>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I would like to do something like:

```
<div style='top: <script>get last div position</script>px'>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I know how to re-position an element after it has already been defined.  What I want to do is position the element dynamically *as it is being defined*.  In other words, I don't want to "re-position" the element at all -- I want it to be initially positioned based on the location of a different element.

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you well versed in JavaScript DOM manipulations in general and selectors in particular??

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, I am well-versed in JavaScript DOM manipulations in general and selectors in particular.

Comment: There aren't really any interceptors to let you change the way an HTML element is defined - the HTML parser is pretty isolated to native code. So, you're restricted to either changing it after it's define (which you don't want) or defining the object entirely in JavaScript (which would let you set it up how you like before adding it to the DOM, but would cut out most of the convenience of working in HTML). An alternative would be if you can work out how to get your elements to fit naturally in standard layout (with minimal use of position: absolute)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's .prev() method will work:

```
$(element).prev().offset().top
```

Comment: Thanks, but the two elements in question are not siblings and do not share a class in common.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without jquery and without the need for elements to be sequential:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnrbpalmer/w5sck7k3/4/

html:

```
<body>
<div id="div1">
    things
</div>

<div id="div2">
    more things
</div>
 </body>
```

JS:

```
var div1_top = document.getElementById("div1").getAttribute("top");
document.getElementById("div2").setAttribute("top", div1_top);
```

CSS:

```
#div1{
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
#div2{
    right:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**UPDATE** (based on comment):

I may be misunderstanding what you want, but how about the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/johnrbpalmer/8pepcej4/1/):

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="div1">
    things
</div>

<button id="make_div2_button">
    make more things </button>

</div>
 </body>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("make_div2_button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    var top = div1.offsetTop;
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.style.cssText = 'position:absolute; right: 10px; top: ' + top.toString() + 'px;';
var message = document.createTextNode("More things");
div2.appendChild(message);         
document.body.appendChild(div2); 
    })
```

CSS:

```
#div1{
    top:30px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
#make_div2_button{
    left:10px;
    top: 100px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution re-positions the second element after it has already been initially positioned.  I want the initial position to be dynamically determined.